Parallel ASP.NET API calls throw "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."
I have an ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.8) application calling an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API as a service that generates PDF documents. Let's call them "main" and "service".
PDF publishing is done for one or more countries, in a loop, and data fetching and mapping is completely synchronous. After the data is prepared, I am sending one request per country to the service app in parallel.
The service generates HTML using Razor and converts it to PDF using an HTML to PDF library (IronPDF). The file is sent as a response back to the main app.
The code, after renaming and omitting unnecessary parts, is below.
Main:
public async Task PublishDocuments(List<string> countries)
{
    var requests = new Dictionary<string, PublishRequest>();

    foreach (var country in countries)
    {
        // prepare data synchronously
        // add data to requests Dictionary
    }

    using var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    using var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

    var publishTasks = requests.Select(x => GetAndSaveFile(x.Value, x.Key, httpClient));
    await Task.WhenAll(publishTasks);

    // more DB work
}

private async Task GetAndSaveFile(PublishRequest request, string fullFilePath, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    var res = await GetDocument(request, httpClient);
    File.WriteAllBytes(fullFilePath, res);
}

private async Task<byte[]> GetDocument(PublishRequest request, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    var serializedRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

    var content = new StringContent(serializedRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:7000/publish", content);

    return await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}

Service:
app.MapPost("/publish", async (PublishRequest request, HttpContext context) =>
{
    // We are using HTML to PDF library, and rely on Razor for strict typing and intellisense in HTML
    var htmlContent = await RenderRazorViewToStringAsync(context, "Document", request);
    var renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();

    renderer.RenderingOptions.EnableJavaScript = true;
    renderer.RenderingOptions.WaitFor.JavaScript(500);

    var pdf = renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(htmlContent);

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=generated.pdf");
    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(pdf.BinaryData);
}).WithRequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));

This works - up to a certain number of countries (i.e. requests). But if too many requests are sent at once, I start getting these errors, first in PublishDocuments:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()      > at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at PublishService.<PublishDocuments>d__22.MoveNext() in...

With an inner exception:

The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

And in GetDocument:

Error while copying content to a stream.
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at PublishService.<GetDocument>d__22.MoveNext() in ...

With an inner exception:

Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
at System.Net.ConnectStream.IOError(Exception exception, Boolean willThrow)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func6 beginMethod, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
at System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream
stream, TransportContext context)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)

I tried these suggestions, most of which are still present in the code:

Increase timeout on HttpClient instance:
 httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);


Set Expect-100 to false (which I removed when it didn't help):
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;


Passing HttpClient into GetDocument, instead of creating one HttpClient per request

Increase request timeout on the service API method: .WithRequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));


I am still getting the same behavior. This is all on my local machine.
Does anybody know what else I can try?

HttpClient is not meant to be instantiated again and again. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-net-http-httpclient

@KlausGütter that's why I kept this implementation, which instantiates it once and passes it to every Task. But I will look into the four additional Timeouts mentioned at the bottom of the article. Although I'm currently more suspicious of the service application causing the issue.

WireMock.Net can be used to create a http service mock. That could help you to narrow down the problem to Main or  Service.

My bet is that the other service you are sending HTTP requests to is not keeping up to speed. I would suggest to determine what number of countries are causing the issue and put it as max limit (or maybe half of that number?) of conucrrent calls to the 3rd aprty. I would wrap it with some SemaphoreSlim or other locking mechanism

I would suspect that 3rd party server that you are sending HTTP requests to is failing when you overwhlem it with multiple concurrent requests.
You should put limit to concurrent requests being made.
Example implementation with locking mechanism using SemaphoreSlim:
private const int MaxNumberOfConcurrentCalls = 3; // choose the appropriate number
private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, MaxNumberOfConcurrentCalls);

private async Task GetAndSaveFile(PublishRequest request, string fullFilePath, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        var res = await GetDocument(request, httpClient);
        File.WriteAllBytes(fullFilePath, res);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}


Yeah, limiting the number of requests per batch sent is an option I consider, but only as a last resort. The API is not 3rd party, I wrote it. And I'd expect an ASP.NET Core WebAPI to be able to handle more than 20-30 requests at a time.
That's why I suspected some kind of a timeout – I thought, with all the threads being spawned simultaneously, every single request takes unexpectedly long to complete. But I haven't been able to fix it poking around timeout settings...
